Start a screenlocker in user session, from a system wide systemd service
I have seen this question, but the complexity of the answer makes me question if I am on the right path at all.
I want to setup Ubuntu to always start a screenlock on suspend. I also want to do it right, even if my actual usecase does not require it, for the learning experience.
What I am trying to achieve:

System wide setup to start the screenlocker for any user logged in on the computer, on closed lid
each user maybe use environment variables to point to a directory of images, to be used by the screenlocker.

What I have so far:

a script in /usr/local/bin to start the screenlock. This uses xsecurelock
xsecurelock installed
a service in /etc/systemd/system, which calls the script with ExecStart

My issue is to let systemd run the start script, in the currently active session.
I could retrieve the active session with this:
for session_id in $(loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }') ; do
    state=$(loginctl show-session -p State --value $session_id)
    if [[ "$state" == "active" ]] ; then
        active_session_id=$session_id
        active_user=$(loginctl show-session -p User --value $session_id)
    fi
done

, but I don't know how to call the script in that existing session.
I feel that there might be a better simpler way to do this altogether. Should I make a systemd user service? In that case, how do I ensure that all users have such a service?
My best attempt at the locking, using sudo -u to run as the found user, but not trying to reconnect to the session itself:
#!/bin/bash

# Get the active session ID and user for the currently logged-in graphical session

for session_id in $(loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }') ; do
    state=$(loginctl show-session -p State --value $session_id)
    if [[ "$state" == "active" ]] ; then
    active_session_id=$session_id
    active_user=$(loginctl show-session -p Name --value $session_id)
    fi
done

sudo -u $active_user bash -l -c "source ~/.config/xsecurelock.env ; xsecurelock"

, then I export the variables that xsecurelock uses in my user's xsecurelock.env.
It fails because "Could no connect to $DISPLAY":
$ sudo systemctl status lock-on-suspend.service 
× lock-on-suspend.service - Lock screen on suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/lock-on-suspend.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-11-11 09:37:19 CET; 2min 33s ago
    Process: 115803 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/lock-with-image (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 115803 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 46ms

nov 11 09:37:19 L34NJKX3 systemd[1]: Starting Lock screen on suspend...
nov 11 09:37:19 L34NJKX3 sudo[115817]:     root : PWD=/ ; USER=gostervall ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/bash -l -c 'source ~/.confi>
nov 11 09:37:19 L34NJKX3 sudo[115817]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user gostervall(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
nov 11 09:37:19 L34NJKX3 lock-with-image[115818]: 2024-11-11T08:37:19Z 115818 xsecurelock: Could not connect to $DISPLAY.
nov 11 09:37:19 L34NJKX3 sudo[115817]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user gostervall
nov 11 09:37:19 L34NJKX3 systemd[1]: lock-on-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nov 11 09:37:19 L34NJKX3 systemd[1]: lock-on-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nov 11 09:37:19 L34NJKX3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Lock screen on suspend.

Am I on the right path? Should I just try and pass DISPLAY to the subshell?
